# Show username depending on login

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, userid

This is for people building wordpress comment systems. This code determines the post after clicking "reply."

The goal is to get either the name entered in the "author" form, or the user identity (via php), depending on if the person is logged in.

```
success: function(data, textStatus){
  if(data=="success"){
    var avatar = "<?php echo get_avatar($id_or_email, 48,'/Avatar.png' ); ?>";
    var author =  "<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?><?php echo $user_identity; ?><?php else :?>"jQuery('#author').val()  ;
    var authorurl = "<?php the_author_meta( 'user_url'); ?>";
    var timestamp = "<?php printf(__('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()) ?>";
    var commenttext =  jQuery('#comment').val();

    jQuery('<li class="new-post">'+'<div class="comment-author vcard">'+avatar+
    '<div class="comment-meta">'+'<b>'+'<a href="authorurl">'+author+'</b>'+'</a>'+
    '<div class="comment-time-stamp">'+timestamp+'</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>'+
    '<div class="comment-text">'+'<p>'+'<pre class="new-post-pre">'+commenttext+'</pre>'+'</p>'+'</div>'+'</li>').insertBefore(respond);
        statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-success" ></p>');
}
```

This is where the problem is:

```
 var author =  "<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?><?php echo $user_identity; ?><?php else :?>"jQuery('#author').val()  ;
```

Comment: Is this a question or some sort of code patch? Either way without more context it is totally unclear what the issue is

Comment: It's not a patch. It's just the jQuery part of an ajax comment list. The full code is here: http://pastebin.com/UHnPgf4J

The section i highlighted as the problem determines what the user's name is upon posting. It needs to use php if they are logged in and jQuery if they aren't. I am wondering how to make it work.

Why the negative rep?

Comment: Probably because (just as @charlietfl said) you just threw up a bunch of code and did not explain it all that well - you didn't explain exactly what you want to happen, you didn't mention what WAS happening, and did didn't mention what you have tried.

Comment: Gotcha. That wasn't my intention. I'll be more thorough in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missing `endif` in your PHP code and a double quote in wrong place (if I well understand the question) :

```
var author =  <? if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : echo '"'.$user_identity.'"'; else: ?> jQuery('#author').val()  <? endif; ?>;
```

Comment: Thank you SO much. I get it now. The 'php' tag was redundant. missing the 'endif' makes sense.

If I could upvote, I would!